# closehandle API, invalid handle exception on x64 Windows

Tags: windows, debugging, winapi, windows-7-x64

as stated on the official documentation ([closehandle API description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

> If the application is running under a debugger, the function will throw an exception if it receives either a handle value that is not valid or a pseudo-handle value.

For this reason the following code can be used to detect if a program is being debugged (since handle 0x1 is always invalid).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
    bool flag = false;
    __try {
        CloseHandle((HANDLE)0x1);
    }
    __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {
        flag = true;
    }
    if (flag == false){
        printf("Not debugged\n");
    }else{
        printf("Debugged\n");
    }
}
```

I compiled this code using Visual Studio 2008, creating a 32bit binary.

It works correctly on Windows XP and Windows 7 32bit, but it does not work on Windows 7 64bit, because it always returns "Not debugged".

Do you have any idea why this happens?
Thank you.

Comment: This is presumably something to do with the 32-bit emulation layer.  But why don't you just use the IsDebuggerPresent function?

Comment: If he's trying to be 'stealthy' about his debugger detection, then IsDebuggerPresent is much easier to 'bypass' as anyone can just null out the BeingDebugged boolean in the PEB. Avoiding the CloseHandle trick requires a binary detour (again, pretty easy, but raises the bar a bit higher than a simple memory write).

Comment: The exception thrown by CloseHandle API is also useful while debugging an application to detect when an Handle is erroneously closed twice.

I think that this is a bug of the 32-bit emulation layer.
This is quite strange because this different behavior between 32-bit and 64-bit systems is not reported in the official documentation.

Comment: Is the exception not even seen by the debugger?  What if the debugger is also 32-bit?

Comment: I tried with a 32-bit debugger and no exception is detected in Windows 7 64-bit.